# Using raw input to create os.path.join

Tags: python, rename, raw-input

I want to rename a file, using the raw_input. But when i change it, it gives the new name no proper ending of the file type. So I tried to joined is, but it doesn't work.
Help appreciated!

```
import os
Base_TXT =r"C:\file.txt"
rename = raw_input('Would you like to rename the txt?')
if rename == 'yes':
    new_name = raw_input('What is the new name?')
    os.rename(Base_TXT, new_name)
    os.path.join(new_name, '.txt')

else:
    print "no rename made"

print "done"
```

Comment: The call to `os.rename` does the actual renaming, so when you do this before you call `os.path.join`, the renaming will not include the result of `os.path.join`.

Comment: Also, I don't think `os.path.join` works the way you think it does -- I suggest reading the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to make sure that you understand what it's doing.

Comment: `os.path.join("somefilename", ".txt")` results in `somefilename/.txt`. `os.path.join()` just joins pieces of path names using the right path separator ('/' for unix based systems, '\' for windows, ...).

Answer (score 2):

Easy solution if always ".txt" is the file you working with.

```
os.rename(Base_TXT, new_name + ".txt")
```

Other thing: If you dont want your renamed file in your script running folder (you want rename at place) you need to build the destination better.

```
if rename == 'yes':
    new_name = raw_input('What is the new name?')

    dir_name = os.path.dirname(Base_TXT)

    destination = os.path.join(dir_name, new_name + ".txt")

    os.rename(Base_TXT, destination)
```